# I get "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo" error when I use sudo in cron job

Tags: linux, cron, sudo

I dont want  to disable requiretty in sudoers file. Please suggest if there is any other way to start a terminal when I execute scripts in cron job

Comment: If you have `Expect` installed, it includes utilities that will execute programs with a pseudo-tty as stdin.

Comment: Why do not execute the script as the user you want to switch?

Comment: I need sudo execute part of the script. So with the user it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This may be a weird workaround, but you may cron SSH to localhost with -t option to spawn a pseudo-terminal and run a command.